# Freezing row in the middle of Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a fairly large spreadsheet being used as a step by step checklist for testing. At the top there are room for notes, general descriptions to the types of tests covered (and other stuff), and below, around row 20 or so, the header for the list of tests are located. Below there is a grid with test IDs, descriptions, step-by-step instructions and results.

Using the spreadsheet is (to say the least) annoying, as you (as far as I know) can only freeze a given row *and everything above*. Does anyone know if it's possible to freeze row 20 only? A user should scroll down in the spreadsheet until row 20 is the topmost row visible, and then it should remain there for the header to always be visible. Any suggestions on how (and if) this could be accomplished in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly based on Excel 2007, you may have several options:

1. Don't freeze it but split it.
2. Move Row20 up to Row1.
3. Use a New Window (example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/463399/freezing-fixing-cells-into-position)).

Comment: I've considered using both windows and splits, but do you know if  they are kept when opening the document on another computer?